# Android studio says please reinstall androis studio from Scratch

Tags: java, android-studio

When  I open android Studio Bumblebee // 2021.1.1 it says

```
Missing essential plugins:

  com.android.tools.design
  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.
```

Please help!

I tried some tutorials. But none of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried fully uninstalling Android studio and installing it again, as suggested?